# Is it correct to combine active and hover pseudo selector like a:active:hover.?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've seen this somewhere, but I can't find more info telling me if it's correct:

```
.selector a:active:hover { color: #777; }
.selector a:hover:active { color: #777; }
```

I don't remember which one of the 2 it was.

But either way, Firefox doesn't seem to like it and does nothing.

Was it another example of a tutorial showing bad practice.??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are fine (and identically equivalent). I've just tested in Firefox 4.0b6/Mac and it works exactly as I would expect. In the below example, the link turns red when I point at it, and then green while I hold the mouse button down.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
a:hover { color: red; }
a:active { color: yellow; }
a:hover:active { color: green; }
</style>
<h1><a href="test">gggg</a></h1>
```

It is unusual to want a link to be styled differently when activated with the mouse than with the keyboard though.

I suspect you may be making a classic mistake. `:active` means "While being activated (e.g. while the mouse button is depressed over it)" and not "When the href attribute's value resolves to the URI of the current page".

There is no pseudo-class that means "When the href attribute's value resolves to the URI of the current page", for that the classic pattern is to add a "current" or "selected" class to the anchor on the server before sending the HTML to the client.

Comment: You're right, it actually works when the mouse is pressed(active). I was expecting this syntax to mean active OR hover, so I only tested the hover, and since it did nothing, I assumed it wasn't working.

Comment: The only way to get a "or" in CSS selectors is with grouping (using a `,` and multiple sets of complete selectors)

Comment: But it remains useless, if it means active AND hover (maybe not useless, but as you said: unusual).  I thought it could be used to combine active and hover, thus reducing the syntax...

Comment: Special casing certain selectors as meaning "or" if combined instead of "and" would be highly unintuitive.

Comment: I can see one use. If you made some kind of button which gets triggered by a mouseup event, clicking and holding the cursor over the button but then moving the cursor away will keep the button :active, but not :hover. So you could make the button look pressed only when :hover:active. Try pressing and holding the close button of your browser, you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

a.selector:active:hover { color: #777; }

a.selector:hover:active { color: #777; }

NOT

.selector a:active:hover { color: #777; }

.selector a:hover:active { color: #777; }

Simple as that :P

Comment: you have no way to know if the class `selector` exists on the `a` element or not, since OP did not post his markup. OP's example would be fine if the container of `a` has the class `selector`.

Answer (score -4):

it is not correct and will not work, you need to separate them out.

```
.selector a:active, .selector a:hover { color: #777; }
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but in CSS, the comma means "or".  The OP is looking for "and".

Comment: No, that is not correct. Comma implies that multiple rules are sharing a definition. without a comma i would be stating I want an element with the class selector, with an anchor element, with another element of selector beneath it.

Comment: To add to it, "AND" is irrelevant. An element cannot be sharing the :active and :hover state at the same time.

Comment: Rubbish. If you are going to activate it with a mouse then it *has* to have the :hover state at the same time (if you are activating with a non-pointing device, e.g. tabbing it into focus then pressing enter, then it won't necessarily be :hover at the same time).

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/css2/sec05-11-03.htm why don't you actually check. You may notice that :active supersedes :hover and they are not both "active" on the element at the same time.

Comment: I'm almost a year late, but `:hover` and `:active` can be, and often are, shared by the same element at the same time. That test is poor because both pseudo-classes use the same `color` rule so one overrides the other. Here's a better example that uses two different styles, so you can observe both apply when you click. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/dWWV9